# SOAP request in PHP in CURL

Tags: php, curl, soap

It's have been already several days since I'm trying to figure out SOAP but no success :( Any chance to know how can I create PHP(curl) SOAP request to look like this?

```
POST /WebServices/domain.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: webservices.domain.ru
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://www.domain.ru/GetVariants"


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
               xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Header>
    <AuthentificationHeader xmlns="http://www.domain.ru/">
      <Login>string</Login>
      <Password>string</Password>
      <PartnerId>string</PartnerId>
    </AuthentificationHeader>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <GetVariants xmlns="http://www.domain.ru/">
      <RequestParameters>xml</RequestParameters>
    </GetVariants>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Also I have following data:

```
WSDL: 
http://webservices.domain.ru/WebServices/domainXml.asmx?WSDL
Soap action: 
http://webservices.domain.ru/WebServices/domainXml.asmx?op=GetVariants
```

Comment: The links return `404 not found`

Answer (score 0):

Basically:

1. PHP's support for SOAP just sucks.
2. You need to use your WSDL to generate your PHP classes, so you can build a Request object.

You will get something like this:

```
class SomeClass
{
    var $name; //NCName
}
class SomeOtherClass
{
    var $value; //anonymous2
}
.
.
.
```

There are some WSDL to PHP scripts out there. (Google wsdl to php)

Then you do something like this.

```
$soapClient = new SoapClient($this->_wsdlUrl, array(
                'trace' => true,
                'exceptions' => true,
                'uri' => $this->_endPoint,
                'location' => $this->_endPoint,
                'local_cert' => $this->certificatePath,
                'allow_self_signed' => true,
                'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2,
            ));
// Build the SOAP client object, with your properties.

//After that, you have to call:
$yourContainerObject = new YourContainerObject(); // The top SOAP XML node 
$yourContainerObject->SomeChildNode = new SomeChildNode();
$yourContainerObject->SomeChildNode->Name = 'John';
.
.
.

$soapResponse = $soapClient->GetVariants($yourContainerObject);
print_r(soapResponse); // to see what you get
```

The "GetVariants" method doesn't need to be implemented, so you don't get confused and ask yourself where do I get that from.It is described in WSLD and PHP's SOAP client knows that it is just a SOAP action.

This should be an more advanced example of creating SOAP requests via PHP.
I hope you get the basic flow of this.

Comment: Unfortunately but I can't make it as separate class because I already have curl multi implemented with other wsdl sources (they worked fine, I just stacked on this one). Any curl solutions?